# VBA string search within files in directory not working in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to look for a string within a folder containing several files. Once the string is found it should select and copy a value in an adjacent cell 5 columns to the right`(Offset(0,5))`, then paste it in my workbook. If more strings are found, they should be pasted as a list End(xlDown).

That's the idea but I can't get it to work, the error message: "**Subscript out of range**".

```
Sub searchBOM()

Dim BOM As String 'the text i'm gonna look for
Dim path As String 'the folder containing several files
Dim filename As String 'one of the files to search in

path = "D:\folder\"
filename = Dir(path)
BOM = InputBox("please enter bom code") 'where the user enters the string

If BOM = "" Then
        MsgBox ("please input valid BOM code") 'not important really, just a small validation
   Else
        Do While filename <> "" 'so the DIR function scans all files
              **'here I get the error message SUBSCRIPT OUT OF RANGE:**
              Workbooks.Open(path & filename).Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Find(BOM).Offset(0, 5).Copy

              'the macro never gets to this line: 
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c" & Range("c5").End(xlDown).Row).Paste
              Workbooks.Open(path & filename).Close
              filename = Dir
        Loop

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach of getting closer to the real problem:

Split the very long line which causes the problem into smaller parts, e.g.

```
  Set wrkbk = Workbooks.Open(path & filename)
  Set sht = wrkbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set rang = sht.UsedRange
  Set fnd = rang.Find(BOM)
  If Not (fnd Is Nothing) Then
     cpy = fnd.Offset(0, 5).Copy
  End If
```

Then you'll find that the problem is in the line `Set sht = wrkbk.Sheets("Sheet1")`.

This means: there is one workbook that does not have a sheet called "Sheet1". Maybe the sheet was renamed by the user.

When Excel stops at the error, right click on `filename` and choose `Add watch` to see which file is affected by the wrong sheet name.

Comment: You were absolutely right! One of the sheet names was in spanish, in order to avoid this potential problem I used a "for each wks in worksheets" to look in all sheets independently of its name.  Do yo know how could I program the macro to search only excel files in that folder? thank you.

Comment: I think you can use `path = "D:\folder\*.xslx"`

Comment: Didn't work, it concatenates as a string the path and the name of the first file. That gets me a message:  "D:\folder\*.xslxfile1.xlsl" could not be found... It runks ok when I include "On error resume next" but I wanted to be more selective with the files to open.